# ASP.Net Charting not available

Tags: visual-studio-2008, charts

I'm at wits end now, I have googled this to death and found nothing.

I have Visual Studio 2008 Professional installed with Service Pack 1. I have also installed .Net Framework 3.5 SP1 obviously. I have installed ASP.Net Charting as well the VS08 addon. Yet I cannot find the  control anywhere. I have tried adding the controls from the installed DLL's but I get the error: "No controls found in this assembly". I have even uninstalled and re-installed everything on my machine.

What am I doing wrong or am I looking in the wrong place entirely?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the issue where the tool did not appear, I added the tool manually. When you browse for the dll, there should be 4 dll's in that folder, 2 for web and 2  for windows forms, of the 2 dll's, theres one with design in the namespace, you want the other one. Sorry its a bit cryptic, I don't have access to a pc with it on at the min, but will check later for the full name.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks so much. I tried everything except linking to the second DLL. You're a champ!